# How to know when a new hyperlink is added to a worksheet using an event

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, event-handling

I need my code to automatically change the font of my newly created hyperlink name and change it's other font properties so I need my code to detect when a new hyperlink is added to a worksheet.

"Worksheet_Change" and "Worksheet_FollowHyperlink" didn't help.

Update: Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim TA As ListObject
Dim TA_DateCol As ListColumn

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WS = WB.Sheets(1)
Set TA = WS.ListObjects(1)

If Not Intersect(Target, TA.Range) Is Nothing Then
    'This is the part which I want my code to detect if a new hyperlink
    'is added but nothing happens my guess is it's because 'Target' type
    'in this event handler is a 'Range' not a 'Hyperlink'
End If

End Sub
```

Any help and advise would be appreciated.[The Picture of my code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5pvj.png)

Comment: Why didn't `Worksheet_Change` work? Can you provide what you tried to help illustrate a picture as to what you were trying to accomplish? Even if the code is completely broken, it may still help us understand better what your end goal is.

Comment: I have added a picture of my code so far. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not show your code as image, you can easily copy and paste the code into the question. You are making it difficult for people to debug your issue as we can't copy and paste the code.

Comment: Adding a hyperlink to a range does not trigger the worksheet_change event. I suppose you want be able to check that. Another option would be to update the hyperlink-style of the workbook to your requirements, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-font-format-for-hyperlinks-672c2905-ad3e-40be-b281-811e68386243

Comment: Thanks Ike but I want my workbook to do that automatically.

Comment: You have to adjust the style only once - any time you add a new hyperlink the style will be applied automatically to the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a hyperlink to a range does not trigger the worksheet_change event.

Therefore it is not able to detect this via code.

The solution is to update the hyperlink style of the workbook to your requirements.

There are quite a lot of tutorials that explain how to do that, e.g. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-font-format-for-hyperlinks-672c2905-ad3e-40be-b281-811e68386243